# Managing y axis offset (large) numbers to show in y-ticks instead of at the top by default

Tags: python, largenumber, yticks

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y=[10001, 10002, 10000]
plt.plot(y,'o--')
```

[plot showing offset number on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mpcbc.png)

In this image, the y ticks are corresponding the remainder of the numbers beyond 10000, which is shown on the top. I do not like this behavior and like to turn it off by default if possible.

I could not find the answer. I don't know if manually controlling the tick positions is going to fix this but I prefer to disable this way of plotting by default.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

Turn off scientific notation for axis plots. This happens under 'ticklabel_format' as follows

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y=[10001, 10002, 10000]
plt.plot(y,'o--')
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Style did not solve the problem. But this

"plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)" solved it

Comment: Okay, I see what you were looking for now.

Answer (score 0):

To change for a plot
`plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)`

To change default setting
`plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.useoffset'] = False`